# Install APK programmatically - return value

Tags: android

In my app, I am calling a javascript interface from my activity. In the webview associated with this interface, I am asking the user to download and install an APK. I am using a "startActivityForResult" to start the install process (after downloading the file). Here is the code:

```
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        promptInstall.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(PATH + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivityForResult(promptInstall, ACCEPT_INSTALL);
```

I am using "onActivityResult" in the main activity class to capture the return value from the above activity. Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("requestCode, resultCode from Install APK: ", Integer.toString(requestCode) + ", " + Integer.toString(resultCode));   
}
```

The problem I am facing is that "resultCode" always returns 0, irrespective of whether the user chose to install the app or not install the app. I really need to know whether the user installed the app or not. Any ideas as to why the return value is always 0?

My last resort would be to use packagemanager to check for the existence of the app in the onActivityResult function to determine if the app was installed or not, but I would like to know why the return value is always 0.

Thanks much...

Comment: I am also facing the same problem and it is ridiculous

Answer (score 3):

We developed an app market and faced the same problem. Our solution was to use the packet manager as you propose.

I looked into some intent-filters as there seem to be some intents around the installation process. But we were not able to get it running. The packet-manager solution works fine tho as you can check the app version which is important on app-updates.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will end up using PackageManager to check if the user installed the app or not.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the **firstInstallTime**/**lastUpdateTime** and compare with your request time to PackageInstaller for install your package, see example below:

```
try {

    PackageInfo installedPackageInfo = getPackageManager()
            .getPackageInfo(installedPackageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
    long firstInstallTime = installedPackageInfo.firstInstallTime;
    long lastUpdateTime = installedPackageInfo.lastUpdateTime;

    // installationRequestTime is the time which you request for the PackageInstaller to install your package. This time should be got from System.currentTimeMillis()
    return firstInstallTime > installationRequestTime || lastUpdateTime > installationRequestTime;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    // First time installation and user choose to not install the app
    return false;
}
```

That solution isn't pretty, but unfortunately PackageInstaller don't provide a clear resultCode to us.