# Catch Installation failure when doing it programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a rooted android device where I download and install the update programmatically. While installing there is no pop up for user, asking for permission to install or showing any error which could have happened during installation. Everything happens in the background. Below is my `SoftwareInstallActivity` which performs the installation.

```
public class SoftwareInstallActivity extends Activity{

private TextView titleView;
private ImageView loadingView;
private String fileName =null;
private static Logger log=Logger.getRootLogger();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alert_screen);
    log.debug("Launching SoftwareInstall Activity");
    fileName=getIntent().getExtras().getString("FileName");
    if(fileName==null && fileName.length()==0){
        log.debug("filename is null or of zero length");
        return;         
    }
    log.debug("Name of apk file"+fileName);
    loadingView       = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.loading);          
    titleView         = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
    log.debug("Starting software Install");
    titleView.setText("Installing Software Update");
    try{
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType( Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName)), 
        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
        startActivity(intent);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    log.debug("On Resume Software Install activity.");
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    log.debug("On Pause Software Install activity.");
}

}
```

The issue I am facing is in few of my trials the software install is failing without even giving any exception. It is very rare scenario but I still want to handle it. So is there any way to find out if the installation actually succeeded or not i.e **Is there any way to catch the success or failure of below given set of lines?**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType( Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName)), 
        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use startActivityForResult, that ways will be able to check the response. Check:
[startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

Comment: The problem with startActivityForResult is it always returns 0(both failure or success). Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157567/install-apk-programmatically-return-value).

Comment: You can use startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode) and than check the requestCode and data in onActivityResult method.

Comment: I tried but for both failure and success the requestCode and responseCode are same i.e responseCode is 0 and requestCode is the integer I am passing

Comment: Because of this I am not able to differentiate between success and failure.

Comment: Sorry, i thought this action works like sharing. In this scenario, you have to catch google play intent in your app and you have to know differences btw sucsses,fail and cancel intents. You may use Intent inceptor (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept) to listen google play intents and their scheme etc. I think you can catch these intents but i didn't try before.